# Generic function including another function, propagating arguments

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to use sympy to help me simplify an expression, however part of what I need to carry forward are the function arguments. This is a toy problem, but something along these lines:

[image: example_equation]

So far I know I can create generic functions, but propagating arguments has eluded me:

```
tau_1, tau_2, tau_3, x = symbols("tau_1, tau_2, tau_3, x")
f = Function("f")
g = Function("g")
h = Function("h")
delta = Function("delta")
f = tau_1 + delta(x)
g = f(x + tau_2)
```

This results in the following:

```
TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

Is it possible to do what I'm looking for in `sympy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is a difference between expressions and functions. For example, `expr = sin(x) + cos(x)` is an expression; it is not callable, meaning you can't do `expr(y+1)` or anything like that (you can do `expr.subs(x, y+1)`, though).

If you want something that looks like sin(x) + cos(x) but is a function, use [`Lambda`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=lambda#sympy.core.function.Lambda) (which is SymPy's version of Python's `lambda`).

```
f = Lambda(x, sin(x) + cos(x))
```

Then `f(y+1)` is `sin(y+1) + cos(y+1)`.

In your notation, that would be

```
f = Lambda(x, tau_1 + delta(x))
g = Lambda(x, f(x + tau_2))
```

Now g(2) is `tau_1 + delta(tau_2 + 2)`

Also, note that `f = Function("f")` is of no consequence because it's overwritten by `f = ...` later. You probably thought of statement `f = Function("f")` as a kind of type declaration: "I declare that f is a function, and expect subsequent assighments to f to know it's a function". But it's just an assignment, not a type declaration; and therefore is overwritten by any subsequent assignment.  Saying `f = Function("f")` means you created an undefined function f, and that is it. SymPy objects are immutable, one can't add more features to f later, one can only overwrite it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! The lambdas seem to be exactly what I need. Yes, I figured that's what was happening with `f`, I was just trying to explicitly convey to the reader that I wanted `f` to be a function and not an expression.